# Twilio how to get rid of prompt to accept call?

Tags: twilio

When a phone recieves a outbound call from my twilio application the caller is hears "you are recieving a call from number xxx-xxx-xxxx press any key to accept. How can I get rid of this an have the call be recieved like an average phone call.

Comment: What are you using for your backend? Sounds like you are describing an OpenVbx functionality option

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using OpenVbx, from the description in your question. 
to turn off the prompt that you are hearing, you can go into the dial applet that you have configured and turn off the whisper option.

Just be careful, as this option is actually overcoming another problem you might encounter, which is if the device you are calling is for example a mobile device and it switches over to voice mail. The whisper option when enabled of course will not pass the call to the device, as the whisper option required human intervention by pressing a button on their keypad to accept the call. If this is not a problem for you, then you can simply turn whisper off.

Hope this helps.